# Meaning of 散斎条 in this context?

Tags: kanji

I'm trying to translate the following sentence,
八世紀の「養老神祇令」散斎条に、唐の令にはみられない肉食禁止条項が挿入されていること
, but can't figure out the meaning of 散斎条.
Searching the almighty google didn't yield any results either.

It's referred to as 「養老神祇令」散斎条, so apparently a part of, or law in,
the Yoro-Code (which is a revision of the Taiho-Code from 701)

Sadly I can't find any translations or explanations about this, or a list of
laws from that code. Even a japanese friend of mine couldn't help.

Update: While the meaning is now more or less clear, I am still strugling to find a fitting translation for "散斎". 
Also, do you think, 養老神祇令  can be translated as "The Law of the Gods of Heaven and Earth during the Yoro period"?

Thank you for your help and suggestions in advance.

Comment: "Searching the almighty google didn't yield any results either."?  It is all over internet.  What are you talking about?

Comment: A fitting translation would depend on how precise you need to be. If you just need to put the point across in context, 八世紀の「養老神祇令」散斎条 can be reduced to “eighth-century ritual codes/laws” or something like that. For academic precision I'm unable to help.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.sol.dti.ne.jp/hiromi/kansei/yoro06.html#11) is a list of those laws, including the specific 散斎条.

After some cursory Googling, `散斎` seems to be a ritualistic period of time where people avoid doing normal activities, somewhat like Passover or Shabbat.